# Replace rule also matching complex numbers

Tags: replacement

I'm having the replace rule:

```
rule = {-g_ x_^4 - 2 g_ x_^2 y_^2 - g_ y_^4 -> -g (x^2 + y^2)^2};
```

Now,

```
(2 Re[Hy Conjugate[Hx]] kx^4 vx vy)/(k^2 (kx^2 + ky^2)) + (
 4 Re[Hy Conjugate[Hx]] kx^2 ky^2 vx vy)/(k^2 (kx^2 + ky^2)) + (
 2 Re[Hy Conjugate[Hx]] ky^4 vx vy)/(k^2 (kx^2 + ky^2)) //. rule
```

Just spits the same expression back out. The expected output would be

```
(2 Re[Hy Conjugate[Hx]] (kx^2 + ky^2) vx vy)/k^2
```

Sure, I could remove the minus signs in the rule, but is it possible to match both `+` and `-`? Furthermore this also fails of one of the coefficients is a complex number, how can I tell Mathematica that this should also work with complex numbers?

If there is another way to do this, e.g., using `Solve`, I'd like to hear that.

Comment: Can you also post your expected output? It's not clear what you want the final result to be

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? This looks like you're trying to re-code some simplifying algorithm that may already be implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: @David: I have done so. The real expression is much longer, so `Simplify` does things that I don't want it to do! I have 'fixed' everything with the replace rules, but this term doesn't want to change :-).

Comment: When I replace `//. rule` by `// Simplify` I get pretty much your desired output; I assume the discrepancies are typos.

Comment: Could just use Factor on your expression, in this case at least.

Comment: Typo: the denominator `(k^2 (ky^2 + ky^2))` should be `(k^2 (kx^2 + ky^2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do all this with replacement rules rather than some built-in functions as noted in the comments, if you modify the rule and correct the typos you get the desired output from the example. For example:

```
 rule2 = g_  x_^4 + h_   x_^2  y_^2 + g_  y_^4 /; h == 2 g -> 
  g (x^2 + y^2)^2 ;
```

and

```
(2 Re[Hy Conjugate[Hx]] kx^4 vx vy)/(k^2 (kx^2 + ky^2)) + (4 Re[
  Hy Conjugate[Hx]] (kx^2  ky^2) vx vy)/(k^2 (kx^2 + 
   ky^2)) + (2 Re[
  Hy Conjugate[Hx]] ky^4 vx vy)/(k^2 (kx^2 + ky^2)) //. rule2
```

gives

```
 (2 (kx^2 + ky^2) vx vy Re[Hy Conjugate[Hx]])/k^2
```